# Use DataLoader Tensorflow for a large pickle size

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle, dataloader, oom

I have pickle 2 pickle for trainSet and testSet such as data.plk , lables.plk
for example for train data pickle have size 2GB.

I want to use this pickle file for fit model and get error OOM (out of memory) when fit model.
I want to use dataLoader for pick batch of data , withoud load full pickle file...

please get me toturial or example code for this problem